# A ghostscript scipt no longer working: pdfwite needs an output file

Tags: ghostscript

I have been using this file for quite some time, today it stopped working:

```
C:\"Program Files"\gs\gs9.53.2\bin\gswin64 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPrinted=false -dPassThroughJPEGImages=false -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dColorImageResolution=400 -dDownsampleGrayImages=true -dGrayImageResolution=400 -dDownsampleMonoImages=true -dMonoImageResolution=400 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=FalterinLenzkirchV2_Compressed.pdf FalterInLenzkirchV2.pdf
```

I am very surprised; the error message is

> 'pdfwrite' requires an output file but no file was specified

The output file is there
Since this a batch sript not being changed, I wonder what else has changed which I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

"C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.53.2/bin/gswin64c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPrinted=false -dPassThroug hJPEGImages=false -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dColorImageResolution=400 -dDownsampleGrayImages=true -dGrayImageResolution=400 -dDownsampl
eMonoImages=true -dMonoImageResolution=400 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=annots.pdf examples/annots.pdf

WORKSFORME -- Please try with that input file, and if that doesn't work we will need to get your input file.

Comment: even `c:\programme\gs\gs9.53.2\bin\gswin64.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -sOutputFile=FalterinLenzkirchV2_Compressed.pdf .\FalterInLenzkirchV2.pdf` does not work; ERROR  /undefinedfilename in (.pdf)

Comment: The file input file opens in Adobe Reader DC.

Comment: I could compress the file using Adobe Acrobat!